# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

The matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix} {0} & {-1} \\ {-1} & {0} \end{bmatrix} $$

has the following eigenvalues and eigenvectors

$$ \begin{aligned} 
   \lambda_{1} = -1, &\qquad \nu_{1}=( 1,1) \\
   \lambda_{2} =  1, &\qquad \nu_{2}=(-1,1) \end{aligned} $$

This makes sense to me, however, there is an additional eigenvector pair I would expect (with same eigenvalues as specified above). Namely, the base vectors
$\nu_{x}=(1\,0)$
$\nu_{y}=(0\,1)$
. I have learned that eigenvectors are all vectors that do not get knocked of their span when the linear transformation occurs. Isn't that the case for the base vectors in this '180 degree' rotation?

Comment: Wecome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Why would you expect the base vectors to be eigenvectors?

Comment: Because the base vectors are still located on their initial span, namely x and y axis. 
The only thing that changes is their sign, so it's comparable to 
1 * v, where v = v_x or v_y

Comment: If you plug $\begin{pmatrix}1 &0\end{pmatrix}^T$ into the matrix, the result is $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1\end{pmatrix}^T$ which is not a scalar multiple.

Comment: Looks like I can't to elementary math lol. Realising that I was thinking of {{-1,0},{0,-1}} and somehow mixed up the two matrices. Thanks for pointing out my brain fart!

Comment: This is not a rotation matrix.   It is a reflection matrix about the line $y = -x$

Comment: About your last sentence : the 180° rotation (which can be considered as well as a **symmetry with respect to a point, the origin**) has the very different matrix $\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}$. Here, the matrix you give corresponds to a **symmetry with respect to a  line** which is not at all a rotation.